Join and Cancel - use Include or Extend?
Image here
I have a Use Case Diagram for our Event Management Platform and our group is having a fight. I wonder in these two which is correct:

Cancel EXTENDS Join (in my view, we can choose to Cancel or not after we Joined).

Cancel INCLUDES Join (in my view, we can Cancel only if we already Joined, similar to we can only Log out after we have Logged in, so Log out includes Log in).


Before, I saw a Use Case Diagram has every function for a user includes the Login. I don't know if it's right, but like if we do the functions, we have to be logged in already, so they used include.
There is also a post about a similar aspect but I feel like it was a bit too complicated for me to understand, and also, most of them were about different issues in my perspective.
I feel like those two mentioned are correct on their own, so can anyone explain me this please, thank you!

Neither. Cancel and Join are independent use cases. Cancel has a precondition that says that the user has to be joined.

In my prof's idea, when the user has to be joined first before cancel, it means that we have to have an include or extend thing?

I second both @GeertBellekens comments.
The two use cases are separate. You join (I'm assuming it's more of a "register" than join actually) and as a result you are in the event.
Of course, you being joined/registered as a precondition for cancelling (i.e. you must have done it earlier), but your decision to Cancel is a separate one to Joining/Registering.
Despite my best attempts I can't find a scenario where either one includes or extends the other.

It's like we have an account already and now we can join event, or leave. In my case I just want to ask if we choose to Cancel, we must have joined already, specifying include. On the other hand, we can choose to Cancel or NOT if we have logged in, specifying extend.
